# Can i store more than one value in Runonce RegKey?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, runonce

I am fixing a testing code, it test a prebootstrapper in a specific software (ensuring that proper .NET is installed , etc..), at some point, the computer must restart, and then continue excuting the testing code **AND** the prebootstrapper after restarting,  the prebootstrapper use the Runonce key in the registry to continue after restart, but also the testing code do this, and the Runonce value get overriden by the testing code, leading to only the testing code running again, can i stack two values in the RunOnce key so both of them restart simultantiously?

If not, is there any other option i can use?

P.S:I code in Python 2.7

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: You can have multiple *RunOnce\description=command_line* keys .

Comment: Each command to run is a *value* in the `RunOnce` *key* that has some unique *name*, and the command line itself is the *data*. If that's not obvious, then I think you must be calling `_winreg.SetValue`, which only sets the default (unnamed) value for a key. You want to call `_winreg.SetValueEx` instead.